# How many bits are you limited to with bitwise permissions?

Tags: php, permissions, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I have been looking at PHP's bitwise permission systems and am looking to implement them into a system I am creating, however I'm not sure on what I'm limited to.

Some websites say 32 bits is the limit some say 64 and other go beyond that to 128, so what exactly is the limit if there is one?

Can I just keep going (depending on the amount of permissions needed) as long as I increment in doubles?

Comment: If you're using an integer value to store the permission data, then your limit is 32-bits with a 32-bit version of PHP, or 64-bits with a 64-bit version of PHP. Most hosts and ISPs only use 32-bit PHP

Comment: You can use several "blocks" of 32, that's not as nice anymore compared to using just one int, but essentially you can just keep going..